# Ping request timeout on macOS

Tags: macos, timeout, ping, macos-big-sur

I am running macOS Big Sur version 11.3.1 (20E241).

My internet connection works. I do not have my firewall active.

I still cannot ping any IP address. It fails with:

```
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

While trying to filter out the possible problems, I connected my laptop to a different network (mobile 4G) and the ping worked. So, the problem is not anything related to a configuration in my laptop but in my router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was not related to MacOs but with my router configuration.

I am using a tp-link C50 Archer.

The router has a security session where it offers to checkboxes:

- Forbid Ping Packets From LAN Port
- Forbid Ping Packets From WAN Port

Those were selected and that was the issue.

Unchecking those options the timeout was gone.

Comment: Thank you, that was my problem too. I am using a tp-link router.